# Access files under path given by genrule in Buck

Tags: buck

How can I reference files inside a directory path given by a `genrule`? I'm trying the following but it doesn't seem to work:

```
http_file(
    name = "some_file",
    ...
)

genrule(
    name = "zip_structure",
    srcs = [":some_file"],
    bash = 'mkdir -p ${OUT}/bin; cp ${SRCS} ${OUT}/bin;',
    out = "zip_contents",
)

zip_file(
    name = "my_zip",
    srcs = glob(["$(location :zip_structure)/**/*"]), # does not work
    # srcs = glob(["$(location :zip_structure)/*"]), # does not work either
    # srcs = glob([":zip_structure/**/*"]), # does not work either
)
```

I'm basically trying to make a folder structure with a `bin` folder containing an file. I want to zip that `bin` folder.

The problem is that if I reference :zip_structure directly, the out folder of `:zip_structure` (in this case `zip_contents`) gets included as the root folder inside the structure of the final zip.

A workaround would be naming the out folder of the `genrule` to `bin`, that way bin is the root folder inside the generated zip, but it doesn't seem like a proper approach, since I'm only outputting one of the inner folders of the potentially more complex structure.

Comment: Changing genrule output name is the only way to achieve that (except using zip in genrule directly, but that involve other issues like relying on a binary in path).

Answer (score 0):

Check out extract function from buckaroo.
[Code](https://github.com/buckaroo-pm/realm-sync-cocoa/blob/3d41474de231fb3053ad980be28dfe4802c28950/utils.bzl).
[Usage example](https://github.com/njlr/buckaroo-protobuf-example/blob/34ffdf9a96002844ec25f4421e50043993939b62/BUCK).